# Wp Some Pages content Not display in editor after move live server

Tags: content, wysiwyg

We work on multi site which one working well on local.

But i have make site on live server then some pages content not display on wysiwyg editor backend but display on front side.

[This issue arrived when content in special character.](http://s10.postimg.org/80hynluq1/bug.png)

we have use Version 4.2.4

How to fix this one this is wp bug ?

Answer (score 0):

After Change config.php working fine.

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
to
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Whats difference between utf8mb4 vs utf8 on wp.